# Hide border of overlaying divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have these two div's

[image: overlaying divs]

```css
.el-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el-1">
</div>
<div class="el-2">
</div>
```

How can I make them look like this?

[image: Overlayed divs]

Doesn't matter if we somehow merge them together or use SVGs but I need the background to stay transparent

Comment: It isn't the best solution but you _could_ position another div right over the intersection of the borders to cover them up

Comment: @grimsteel Instead of a div, you could also use pseudo-elements.

Comment: Do you want only the borders to "merge" like that, or can we also just hide the unwanted parts like grimsteel suggests? The difference is that the background may not be transparent anymore.

Comment: The problem with overlaying with a rectangular div is that the part you want to get rid of isn't an exact rectangle - two internal corners on the borders get cut off using this method.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the methods suggested which involve an overlay is that the part we want to get rid of is not an exact rectangle. There is a bit in the internal corners which must remain.

This snippet takes a different approach. It uses mix-blend-mode to choose the lighter of the two colors within each div. This gets rid of the black border that lies within it.

To ensure that the blending doesn't also involve any other background the divs are put within a container which is isolated (new staking context).

```css
body {
  /*for demo to show isolation works */
  background: #eee;
}

.container {
  isolation: isolate;
}

.el-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

.el-1,
.el-2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="el-1">
    </div>
    <div class="el-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: as with the other methods suggested this means the rectangles have white rather than transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround for this, which is using `::before` Selector. gonna make a white square which will cover the lines of intersection two `divs`:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}

.el-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

.el-2:before {
  content: '';
  top: -0.8px;
  left: -0.8px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 19.5px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="el-1">
</div>
<div class="el-2">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is giving me a small gap at two intersections and a spurious line remains within the divs. A further part height line shows also but that one comes and goes with zoom. Currently using IOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate it using a drop-shadow on a parent element

```css
.el-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #fff; /* a background is needed*/
}

body {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #000) drop-shadow(0 0 1px #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="el-1">
</div>
<div class="el-2">
</div>
```